# How to disable the textarea's auto-zoom-in in Oracle Apex on mobile?

Tags: css, oracle-apex, textarea

By tapping any field in an Oracle Apex application on mobile, it automatically zooms in on that field.

I have put this code at the CSS section of the page and fixed the problem for most field types.

```
.apex-item-select:focus, .apex-item-text:focus, .apex-item-textarea:focus {

        font-size: 16px;

    }
```

Yet however, the problem still persists for the textareas. I have tried many other ways which worked for every field except the textareas. How can I fix this problem and disable the auto-zoom-in for textareas?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the user-agent styling sets the `outline-offset: -2px;` on focus.
You can override it as:

```
.apex-item-textarea:focus {
  outline-offset: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I have added this code to the initial CSS, but the auto-zoom-in still occurs.

Comment: Then you need to use browser console to navigate the DOM element's style attributes. Check which style attritube changes when you focus on that item and revert it afterwards.